# Implementing Paypal SDK with Android studio - Unable to login from application

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

The activity which calls PaypalService.class :

```
 //PAYPAL SDK VARIABLES
    public static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE = 7171;
    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
```

```
 Intent payPalIntent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
        payPalIntent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        startService(payPalIntent);


        payment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.payment);
        payment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                processPayment();
            }


        });

    }//END OF ON CREATE

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirmation != null) {
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails = confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);

                        startActivity(new Intent(this,GetTheBike.class)
                                .putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
                                .putExtra("PaymentAmount", amount_to_pay)
                        );


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void processPayment() {
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(amount_to_pay), "USD",
                "Pay for parking", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);


    }
}
```

Config.java which is in a different folder. It's able to connect to the application ( Client_id is a valid key)

```
package com.example.becoapk21.Config;

public class Config {
    public static final String PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID="CLIENT_ID";
}
```

I'm logging in with a valid customer sandbox account ( Tested login on sandbox.paypal.com) and this is the error that I get after login

```
E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:404,exception:Not Found
E/paypal.sdk: Exception parsing server response
    org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cw.m(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.fm.d(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.a(Unknown Source:62)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cq.onResponse(Unknown Source:45)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:
E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Note : The paypal sandbox account is located IL . I also tried creating US account and it didn't work

Comment: Using following paypal sdk version `   implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'`

Comment: were you able to find alternative for this?

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a deprecated Android SDK for a service that is now end of life.

See the new [Native Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for that !